# 2D Camera using OpengGl

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I am coding a little game in 2D and I want to implement a camera that follow the characacter when he moves. 
Unfortunately with my implementation my result when I move the character is a black screen ...  Can you help me if you know where my mistake is ? I am new to openGl.

Here is my code with the main code :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

glutInit (&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(300, 350);

glutCreateWindow("Map");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(drawMap);
glutSpecialFunc(specialkeyboard);

glutIdleFunc(moveObjects);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

The function to draw the map : 
    void drawMap()
    {

```
//int x=0;
//Initialisation
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0.0,500.0,0.0,500.0); 
glViewport(0,0,1000,700); 

// drawing the rest of the map //
```

And here the camera code, I think the problem come from the camera function.

```
void camera() {


float left = C.x - (300/2.0); 
float  bottom = C.y - (350/2.0); 

float  right = left + 300;
float  top = bottom + 350;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(left, right, bottom, top); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

And the function specialkeyboard :

```
void specialkeyboard(int key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        C.y += 2;
        camera();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        C.y -= 2;
        camera();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        C.x += 2;
        camera();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        C.x -= 2;
        camera();
        break;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

**EDIT**

So now the problem is that the map move on the wrong direction, it is moving with the character but not following him. (The red circle is the character)

Main code :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

glutInit (&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 700);
glutCreateWindow("Map");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(drawMap);
glutSpecialFunc(specialkeyboard);

glutIdleFunc(moveObjects);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Drawing the map :

```
void drawMap()
{
std::cout << "Debut Drawmap " << std::endl;
//TRY
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluOrtho2D(0.0,500.0,0.0,500.0);
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity ();
}

//drawing the map//

// Red circle
C.DrawCircle();
camera();
glutSwapBuffers ();
std::cout << "Fin drawmap " << std::endl;    
}
```

And the camera :

```
  void camera(){  
  glViewport(C.x,0,1000,700);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

As soon as your `camera()` function is called, you are applying two `glOrtho()` matrices, which is certainly not what you want.

The fixed fuinction GL will apply the product `Projection * ModelView` to each vertex that you draw. Initially, `Projection` will be identity, so it will have no effect, and you are setting `ModelView` to `Ortho2D(0.0,500.0,0.0,500.0)`.

When you draw in that state, a vertex coordinate of `x=0` will be mapped to the left edge of the viewport, and `x=500` will be mapped to the right one. However, that is only the case because the GL will always apply the viewport transform after the matrices have been applied. What `Ortho2D` actually does is create scale and translation  so that the viewing voulme in eye space is transformed to a *cube* from -1 to 1 along all dimensions in NDC space.

Now when you also set the projection matrix to ortho, you will have the following effect:

ModelView will transform `x=0` to -1 and `x=500` to 1. And then, the projection is applied which will map your camera-based `left` to -1 and `left + 300` to 1. If your `C.x` and `C.y` where both zero at that time, you would have the effect that you image would be scaled down to 1/300 and 1/350 of the original size. But since you at least increase or decrease your camera position by two units - which is now exactly the size of your original image region due to the first `Ortho2D` - you guarantee that that point is not on the screen any more at all.

Having said all that, there ae several advices I can give:

1. Do never put an ortho matrix onto the ModelView stack. It is not meant to be used that way.
2. Just keep a single ortho call, on the projection matrix, and dependent on your camera location.
3. Forget everything about `glMatrixMode`, `gluOrtho2D` and so on. These are *deprecated* in the GL since a decade. Modern core profiles of OpenGL do not support that functions at all. If you start learning OpenGL nowadays, don't ever bother with that old cruft which last time made sense in the previous millenia. Learn the proper way by using the programmable pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. I edited the change in the code in my previous post. Now the new problem is that the map moves with the character but not with him. Like when the character moves on the right, the map need to go on the left, here the map goes on the right too

Comment: @Flore: you must not modify the viewport, that has nothing to do with any of that. You actually want to update the ortho call like you did at the beginning, you just need to replace your other ortho call completely.

Comment: So you mean that in the drawmap function I should remove my glortho (and put a viewPort ?). 
And in my camera function I should put 
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(left, right, bottom, top); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

With a glortho and no viewport at all ?

Comment: you need to set a viewport. but it is totally independent of the camera.

Comment: If I understand well, ortho 2D create a scale, so I need it in the function drawmap to define my scale, and with viewport I define the size of my map on the screen. What do you mean by "you just need to replace your other ortho call completely", I am a little lost